# Improving efficiency/speed in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, xml, performance

I'm learning Python and I am trying to read in hundreds of xml files that are several GBs in size, map them to a Pandas dataframe and write a csv file.

The xml files look like this: https://github.com/yadudoc/wos_builder/blob/master/sample.xml

My attempt:

```
import os
import gc
import pandas as pd
import wos_parser as wp

directory = ('./')
year_batch = "2016_123"

def references():
  temp = pd.DataFrame()
  for file in os.listdir(directory):
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     if filename.endswith('.xml'):
         records = wp.read_xml(filename)
         references = [wp.extract_references(record) for record in records]
         references = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, references), sort = True)
         temp = temp.append(references)
         
  temp.to_csv(f'{year}_references.csv', index = False)
```

The code works and is fine for a smaller number of files but becomes totally unscalable on just a few more files...My understanding is that for loops and appending in pandas is a pretty brute force and inefficient way to go about it but that's where I'm at and could use help optimizing my iteration workflow through apply() or other techniques.

I used *line_profiler* to highlight where things are the slowest and it looks like the line where the xml records are being read in is the slowest taking up about 69% of the total processing time:

```
Total time: 800.943 s
File: parse.py
Function: references at line 25

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    25                                           @profile
    26                                           def references():
    27         1        666.0    666.0      0.0    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    28        18        135.0      7.5      0.0    for file in os.listdir(directory):
    29        17         86.0      5.1      0.0       filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    30        17         29.0      1.7      0.0       if filename.endswith('.xml'):
    31         3  554285351.0 184761783.7     69.2           records = wp.read_xml(filename)
    32         3   52565313.0 17521771.0      6.6           references = [wp.extract_references(record) for record in records]
    33         3  193538944.0 64512981.3     24.2           references = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, references), sort = True)
    34         3      82574.0  27524.7      0.0           temp = temp.append(references)
    35                                                    
    36         1     470246.0 470246.0      0.1    temp.to_csv(f'{year}_references.csv', index = False)
```

What is a recommended way to speed up the read_xml function? Is there a clean way to rewrite this as a lambda/apply? I can't quite wrap my head around how apply works since so many examples I see are for smaller toy examples. Thanks for any thoughts or guidance you have.

Edit: changed some code to reflect a more computationally intense example based on the sample file provided.

Comment: This is an unfortunate case, where you yourself have pointed that most time is being taken by the file reading. This is not a weakness in code logic. I would suggest you dive a little deep in python multithreading. It can improve file I/O speed significantly.

Comment: `lambda` is *totally irrelevant here*. This is very important to understand, `.apply` is often paired with a `lambda` expression, but lambda expressions just create functions like *any other*, and you can **always** just use a regular function definition.

Comment: With the above in mind, `.applying` a very slow function, i.e. `wp.read_xml` is not going to be faster (significantly) than a loop that does it. `.apply` is not *meant* to be fast, although it has gotten better lately (I think the pushed some of the logic into Cython), but fundamentally, it is still slow.

Comment: Maybe you can use [`aiofile`](https://github.com/mosquito/aiofile)

Comment: can we have some figure about the size of the corpus, please.
also a sample of data would be useful to test some ideas

Comment: @SawradipSaha Thank you. I will see if I can learn how to apply multithreading in this case.

Comment: @Setop A sample file is here: https://github.com/yadudoc/wos_builder/blob/master/sample.xml

This would be a sample of several hundred files with the total corpus totaling up to about 4-500 Gb. I'm hoping to make all this work on my laptop which is a macbook  with 16Gb RAM

Comment: 69% of the work is `read_xml` and the other 31% of the work is making and merging dataframes. There's no obvious inefficiencies and no quick fix to this. Asynchronous programming may help speed things up if `read_xml` isn't CPU-heavy (the idea is that when the CPU is idle during a file read, you can make it go make some dataframes until the file is read), but you'll have to use asynchronous file I/O functions and rewrite this whole code.

Comment: Did you try `pandas.read_xml` function?

Comment: I would suggest https://youtu.be/IEEhzQoKtQU this video to get started with python multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

I made some tests with [xml pull parser](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/xml.dom.pulldom.html#xml.dom.pulldom.DOMEventStream.expandNode):

```
import sys
from xml.dom.pulldom import START_ELEMENT, END_ELEMENT, CHARACTERS, parse

doc = parse(sys.stdin)
for event, node in doc:
    if event == START_ELEMENT and node.localName == 'reference':
        doc.expandNode(node)
        print(node.toxml())
```

On my laptop, I'm able to parse 2.5MB/s of the sample given, using 18MB of RAM whatever the input size is. This would lead to 55h for 500GB.

Coupled with [`xargs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) for multi processing, this time can be roughly divided by the number of cores of the machine, i.e: 4 cores -> 14h.

Comment: @pocketprotector what is the processing speed with wos_parser ? what are your needs ?